# Knockout Table Sorting, single function for EVERY column?

Tags: jquery, sorting, knockout.js, tablesorter

I have multiple tables that I am populating with Knockout. Currently I am using the knockout sorting method

```
    { return a.total_sales() > b.total_sales() ? -1 : 1; }
    else { return a.total_sales() < b.total_sales() ? -1 : 1; };
```

However, I need to have sorts on every column in every table.  Is there away around writing all those statements?  I looked at jquery tablesorter, but it did not seem to work with my tables.  Many columns are buttons or other objects instead of just text.  If I am stuck using the knockout method I will have well over 100 of these.  Suggestions?

IF needed I can add a table example that fails with tablesorter

Comment: If you use the tablesorter plugin, you'll need to write a parser to to get text, attributes, value or whatever from the buttons and other objects ([ref](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)). If you share some sample HTML, I might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a binding handler to use jquery plugins:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tablesorter = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).tablesorter(options)
    }
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<table data-bind="tablesorter: {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]}"></table>
```

Comment: I have looked into that.  However, it only sorts the one direction and adds a row when I click sort.  I have also tried just adding the tablesorter to an empty table then calling the .trigger("update") but when I try to sort a column it says [0] undefinted, or [1] etc...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
is the error when using  $("#r1table").tablesorter(); to init and $("r1table").trigger("update"); to update